# Automating finding optimal parameters for re-encoding random video files with ffmpeg / avcov

Tags: ffmpeg, avconv

I've done a bit of re-encoding of video with ffmpeg, mainly aimed at recompressing videos from assorted sources (youtube, twitch, tiktok, etc) to reduce file size with acceptable (subjective) amounts of loss in quality.  Given that I know little about the quality setting of the original files (and these vary over time anyway), the process for any one file is very time consuming.  Every time, the process is something like this:

1. Compress a chunk of video
2. Compare the compressed chunk against the original
3. Bump the crf up or down based on how bad the re-encode looks.
4. Repeat until the ideal crf value for a given file is found, or I get tired and give up.

This is essentially the "trial and error" approach that comes up as the only answer every time somebody asks how to find optimal settings.  Trial and error works, of course, but it requires interaction after every loop.  Given that ffmpeg can also calculate the loss for a given encode (PSNR or VMAF), are there any frontends or wrapper scripts implementing an automated process?

A different approach would be a script or frontend that generates a 'contact sheet' of re-encodes, basically re-encoding a small chunk of the original file repeatedly over a range of CRF values.  Does such a thing exist already?  Research how to generate previews of videos has yielded a lot of approaches to creating youtube-like preview snippets, not quality test snippets.

Comment: Quality metrics such as PSNR and VMAF compute some good indicators. Ultimately, nothing beats human perception when it comes to assessing visual quality. I suggest you do a random sample with 20 videos, then select the lowest CRF. I usually go with 21. On average, visual quality and file sizes won't differ much between crf 16 and 26.

Comment: I'm not really looking for a solution for _one_ video or even a class of videos, I'm looking for a solution to the workflow of generating those random samples.  For example, generating 20 re-encodes of a snippet of video with different parameters (along with the corresponding snippet of the original) and presenting those files and their corresponding PSNR/VMAF stats so I can make educated choices.  I don't expect the ideal (subjective) CRF to be the same for all videos, or even all videos from one source.